# ReactJS loop after everytime when I invoked onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, array-map

please, I'm learning React with my simple TODO App. Everything now works OK. No errors or warnings (or issues in browser). But please, can you see the `console.log('PING!')`?

I'm using for list of tasks this loop:

```js
<ul>
  {tasks.map((task, index) => {
     console.log('PING!');
     return (
      <Task id={task.id} name={task.name} isFinished={task.isFinished} key={index}
            onActionButtonClick={handleActionButtonClick}/>
     );
  })}
</ul>
```

`console.log()` it's just for show the problem. `handleActionButtonClick` is used to passing arguments from child `Task`.

But If I type the first task and hit enter (submit form). Everything is OK. I got **PING!** message once. But then it's called after every type new character. I'm using `onChange` event in `<input>`. Look here:

```js
<input
    id="newTaskInput"
    type="text"
    onChange={handleChange}
    value={newTask}
    placeholder="Add new task here..."
    autoFocus
/>
```

`handleChange` functions looks like here:

```js
const handleChange = (e) => {
  if (e.target.value.length === 1) {
     e.target.value = e.target.value.toUpperCase();
  }
  setNewTask(e.target.value);
};
```

This is called aways when I'm typing a new task (after the first one). Look on the screenshot please:

[image]

You can see the first **PING!** was called after submit `Butter` item. But then I'm typing a new item called `Milk` and you can see 4x **PING!** message in console. But I'm just setting the state called `setNewTask` which is `useState`. Look at the definition:

```js
function App() {
  const [newTask, setNewTask] = useState('');
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);
  const [editTaskId, setEditTaskId] = useState();
  // other code
}

export default App;
```

I will be glad if someone can explain me why is `map` function is called everytime after the first submit and how to avoid it. Thanks to any advice

For better understand my logic here is whole code please:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Task from './components/Task';
import Header from './components/Header';

function App() {
  const [newTask, setNewTask] = useState('');
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);
  const [editTaskId, setEditTaskId] = useState();

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.value.length === 1) {
      e.target.value = e.target.value.toUpperCase();
    }
    setNewTask(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (editTaskId > 0) {
      //editing exisitng task
      let newTasksArray = [...tasks];
      let newTask = newTasksArray[editTaskId];
      newTask.name = newTask;
      setTasks(newTasksArray);
    } else {
      //creating new task
      setTasks([
        {
          id: [...tasks].length === 0 ? 0 : Math.max(...tasks.map((task) => task.id)) + 1,
          name: newTask,
          isFinished: false,
        },
        ...tasks,
      ]);
    }
    setNewTask('');
  };

  const handleActionButtonClick = (buttonValues) => {
    switch (buttonValues.type) {
      case 'edit':
        tasks.map((task) => {
          if (task.id === buttonValues.id) {
            setNewTask(task.name);
            setEditTaskId(task.id);
            return;
          }
        });
        break;
      case 'delete':
        setTasks(tasks.filter((task) => task.id !== buttonValues.id));
        break;
      default:
        //TODO: We shoudn't reverse array. Instead of that we shoud find a right id in a array and change value
        console.log(buttonValues.id);
        let newTasksArray = [...tasks].reverse();
        let newTask = newTasksArray[buttonValues.id];
        //if task if already finished we can return state
        if (newTask.isFinished) newTask.isFinished = false;
        else newTask.isFinished = true;

        setTasks(newTasksArray.reverse());
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <div className="container">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <label htmlFor="newTaskInput" className="sr-only">
            Input for new task
          </label>
<input
    id="newTaskInput"
    type="text"
    onChange={handleChange}
    value={newTask}
    placeholder="Add new task here..."
    autoFocus
/>
</form>
<ul>
    {tasks.map((task, index) => {
        console.log('PING!');
        return (
            <Task
                id={task.id}
                name={task.name}
                isFinished={task.isFinished}
                key={index}
                onActionButtonClick={handleActionButtonClick}
            />
        );
    })}
</ul>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Best regards folks.

Comment: Because you are changing a state. Changing any state will rerender the entire component. It is expected behavior and it's fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `tasks` is empty, there are no elements to iterate over. The callback is never entered into, so `console.log('PING!');` doesn't run.

After you've added one item to `tasks`, there's an element to iterate over, so a single log occurs every time there's a re-render. (Because the `<input>` is a controlled component, there's a re-render every time a character is typed or deleted.)

If you add multiple items to `tasks`, on each rerender, there will be a log for each item.

This is the way things are supposed to work in React - every time state changes (such as, when a character is typed), the component containing the state is supposed to re-render; the philosophy in React is for the view to flow from the state, so whenever the state changes, it needs to recalculate the view to see what in the DOM needs to be changed.

If you really need to, you can prevent re-renderings from running the callback again by memoizing the array of Tasks elements with `useMemo` - but it'd make more sense not to bother in almost all situations.

```
const tasksToRender = React.useMemo(() => tasks.map((task, index) => {
    console.log('PING!');
    return (
        <div>{task.name}</div>
    );
}), [tasks])
```

and

```
<ul>
    {tasksToRender}
</ul>
```

```js
const { useState } = React;
function App() {
    const [newTask, setNewTask] = useState('');
    const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);
    const [editTaskId, setEditTaskId] = useState();

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        if (e.target.value.length === 1) {
            e.target.value = e.target.value.toUpperCase();
        }
        setNewTask(e.target.value);
    };

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (editTaskId > 0) {
            //editing exisitng task
            let newTasksArray = [...tasks];
            let newTask = newTasksArray[editTaskId];
            newTask.name = newTask;
            setTasks(newTasksArray);
        } else {
            //creating new task
            setTasks([
                {
                    id: [...tasks].length === 0 ? 0 : Math.max(...tasks.map((task) => task.id)) + 1,
                    name: newTask,
                    isFinished: false,
                },
                ...tasks,
            ]);
        }
        setNewTask('');
    };

    const handleActionButtonClick = (buttonValues) => {
        switch (buttonValues.type) {
            case 'edit':
                tasks.map((task) => {
                    if (task.id === buttonValues.id) {
                        setNewTask(task.name);
                        setEditTaskId(task.id);
                        return;
                    }
                });
                break;
            case 'delete':
                setTasks(tasks.filter((task) => task.id !== buttonValues.id));
                break;
            default:
                //TODO: We shoudn't reverse array. Instead of that we shoud find a right id in a array and change value
                console.log(buttonValues.id);
                let newTasksArray = [...tasks].reverse();
                let newTask = newTasksArray[buttonValues.id];
                //if task if already finished we can return state
                if (newTask.isFinished) newTask.isFinished = false;
                else newTask.isFinished = true;

                setTasks(newTasksArray.reverse());
        }
    };
    const tasksToRender = React.useMemo(() => tasks.map((task, index) => {
        console.log('PING!');
        return (
            <div>{task.name}</div>
        );
    }), [tasks])
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <label htmlFor="newTaskInput" className="sr-only">
                    Input for new task
                </label>
                <input
                    id="newTaskInput"
                    type="text"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    value={newTask}
                    placeholder="Add new task here..."
                    autoFocus
                />
            </form>
            <ul>
                {tasksToRender}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('.react')).render(<App />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for great explain and example. So, it doesn't have some big effort to memory? Because my basic idea was that every re-render may have impact to memory. If is it OK, I will leave it. I wanted to avoid this behavior because memory impact. Thanks

Comment: Right - in most cases, it's unnoticeably cheap.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to avoid rerendering on every char input :

```
<input
    id="newTaskInput"
    type="text"
    onSubmit={handleChange}
    value={newTask}
    placeholder="Add new task here..."
    autoFocus
/>
```

Why ? because on every change happen or char entered you call `handleChange` function which set a new state and rerender the component, and to avoid this you can add a button to submit or track the change and listen for `Enter` key to submit the data.

Comment: Do you mean listen on `Enter` key and `onKeyPress` event?

Comment: Yes, and also `onSubmit` do that, so there's no need to track key unless you need that

Comment: You mean remove the onChange in input field? And get the value from input filed in `onSubmit` ?

Comment: You can still use `onChange` to create another state for the input and add `onSubmit` which will be a small function to add the input text as a new todo item, here's an article which may help https://www.educative.io/blog/react-hooks-tutorial-todo-list

Comment: I must keep onChange and `const [newTask, setNewTask] = useState('')` because I have there to uppercase first-letter. It's impossible to do it with pure CSS. input::first-letter {text-transform: uppercase}` doesn't work. I read, that pseudo classes doesn't work in `input` or `textarea`. So, then it's unimportant if I will get values from `newTask` state or from `e.target[0].value` in `handleSubmit`. But thanks, listening on `Enter` key is a fine. Thanks

Comment: No problem, but that's what I have said, you can still use `onChange` and add the task to `newTask` then add `onSubmit` and assign it to a `handleSubmit` so it will work that way.